# How to recursively add elements to a list based on the evaluation of another function in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, append, scheme

I have the following code in which I am trying to add all elements of a list to a new list based on if they are prime numbers:

```
(define (findPrimes newLis lis)
    (cond
            ((null? lis) ())
            (else 
                (
                    (cond 
                        ((#t (isPrime (CAR lis)))
                            (append newLis (CAR lis))))
                    (findPrimes newLis (CDR lis))
              ))
          )

        newLis
    )
```

I however get an error. I am extremely new to scheme so I apologise if this code is completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have lots of extraneous parentheses. Each pair of parentheses count, in Scheme, we cant just through them around for good measure. *`(f x)`* means *"do call function `f` with an argument `x`"*, so *`((f x))`* means *"call function `f` with an argument `x`, and then treat the result of that call as a function, and call it (again) without any arguments"*. Which is *bound* to cause troubles, more likely than not.

What you meant to write was

```
(define (findPrimes newLis lis)
    (cond
            ((null? lis)   (set! newLis '()))
            (else 
                (cond 
                   ((equal? #t (isPrime (CAR lis)))
                           (set! newLis 
                                 (append newLis (list (CAR lis))))
                           (findPrimes newLis (CDR lis)))
                   (else
                           (findPrimes newLis (CDR lis)))))))
```

but that's all kinds of wrong. For starters, `(findPrimes '() (list 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))` doesn't return anything -- no matter the arguments.

You need to change the base case handling. In the recursive case you build up the list passed in as the first argument; then, when we've reached the end of the input list (second argument), what do you do with the new list that is now ready? You set it to `'()`! And you return no value (because `set!` doesn't return any value).

So this is easy to fix: just return the value that you've built. The value of the last expression is what is returned as the value of the whole function. And you have the value you want returned, the new list. So you make it be the last expression in the base case `cond` clause. So now it works.

But, it isn't working *well*. It is *quadratic* in time (because of repeated `append`). This usually means disastrously slow execution times. Also, the use of `set!` is an indicator that something's might not be quite right.

The usual Scheme way of doing this is,

```
(define (findPrimes lis)
    (cond
            ((null? lis)               '() )
            (else 
                (cond 
                   (           (isPrime (CAR lis))
                           (cons                      (CAR lis)
                             (findPrimes        (CDR lis))))
                   (else
                             (findPrimes        (CDR lis)))))))
```

see how much less stuff you had to type in?

Here it is again, with the normal spacing:

```
(define (findPrimes lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) '() )
    ((isPrime (car lis))
     (cons (car lis)
           (findPrimes (cdr lis))))
    (else
     (findPrimes (cdr lis)))))
```

There was one or two more things that I've changed there as well. Can you tell what it was?

Comment: Hi, this unfortunately does not produce the correct result. 
   (findPrimes ’(4 7 10 2 -1)) returns $1 = (7 -1). And (findPrimes ’(4 10 1 8 -2)) gives a really weird error.

Comment: but wait, before that, why are you using negative numbers? is your `isPrime` working with them (and 1) correctly? Debug *it* first.

Comment: https://ideone.com/cjwOMf here is the link. I hope it is the correct one. I haven't used ideone.com before

Comment: and what does `(recIsPrime -1)` return? and  `(recIsPrime 1)` ?

Comment: Are you not able to edit that? The input and output I mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182612/discussion-between-will-ness-and-keagansed).